# How to add event listener to each element in an array?

Tags: javascript

So lets say that I have an array of 4 divs named elements, and to add eventlistener to each of them.

I used this `elements.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('clicked', () => console.log('clicked')))`

And it console logs only when i click on the last element. When i click on other elements nothing happens

Comment: `'clicked'` or `'click'` ?

Comment: Oh this actually was the case .... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such event named `clicked` in Javascript, update it with [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) to make it works.

```
elements.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked')))
// here ---------------------------------^^^^^^^-----
```